# phpMyAdmin sometimes gives me "Operation timed out" on login

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

recently we have migrated to new server, I'm using phpMyAdmin to connect from my local machine to the remote mysql server to browse the database. Since then I have this annoying problem, in 50% of the cases when I try to log in phpmyadmin gives me

> Cannot log in to the MySQL server
>
> mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Operation timed out

[image]

After a few tries it works and I'm logged. But then comes another problem, after executing several queries again timeouts and I have to login again. I think it's not firewall problem, because sometimes works.

Comment: Is it online? I faced the same problem too. But for my case, it's not coding kind problem. But the internet connection. I switch to use other VPN and its ok. It is because my server has some setup for security and avoid unknown/suspicious IP address and automatically set the session end. Try to connect with other internet connection if it help.

Comment: could it be a ipv6/ipv4 issue? what host do you connect to? try using explicit ip

Comment: I'm using explicit ip.

Answer (score 0):

increase the  $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] value from php.ini file,it will work.

Comment: Thanks, I've set the config, it seems to be ok now, let me try it for a few days.

Comment: it worked for me many times.If its not work for you then there will be the problem of firewall.